# When should I use methods, get() and magic offset

Tags: 8, entities

There are three different ways to get an entity value, for example the node content type.

- `$node->type->value`
- `$node->getType()`
- `$node->get('type')`

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is a specific method - as for `$node->getType()` - I'd recommend using this one. Obviously that's never the case for dynamic stuff like fields - for that `$node->type->value` would be the recommendation.

Edit: `$node->get('type')` is just a more verbose variant of `$node->type` - both get you the "type" field object.

Answer (score 7):

A specific method IMO is always preferred because of the `@return` typehint. You can't really typehint the return of a `get('foo')`. And, magic will always be slower and also an unknown to IDEs on what is returned. (Note that every time we are talking IDEs we are also talking possible bugs -- not just the IDE but the programmer has no knowledge of what's in a variable.)