# What is the correct way to get the value of a field?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

We have several fields on the `Article` content type such as `field_headline` (plain text field). When we try to access the value of this field in a module hook such as `mymodule_preprocess_page` (mymodule.module), we have found several ways to do it.

What is the correct way to get the value of the fields?

Example:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  // These both work. 
  $node->get('field_headline')->value;
  $node->get('field_headline')->first()->getValue()['value'];
}
```

Comment: Both work, but both with different output, no?

Comment: @leymannx they return the same values, which in the case of `field_headline` is a `string` value.

Comment: Hope someone else adds their expertise in a proper answer. If I remember it right `->value` is a magic method whereas `->getValue()` is not. And from what I looked up so far it seems that magic method calls are considerably slower than non-magic ones.

Comment: Here's another one: [EntityNG: When to use methods, get() and magic offset](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85351/entityng-when-to-use-methods-get-and-magic-offset)

Comment: Only difference here, there is no `first()`, which adds another dimension: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/drupal-8-get-value-of-field-user-in-proper-way-not-an-array

Comment: @leymannx that article does a good explanation of what I needed.